# Magento 1..9.x Backup Unzip Failure

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, backup

I am running Magento 1.9.2.1 on a Windows 2008 Server with MySQL. For some odd reason when I go into the Magento Admin area to perform a database backup that seems to work fine until I download and try to unzip it using 7zip. When I do I get an error that says "Data Error in 45943592_db_test File is Broken". Does anyone have any idea why this could be and more importantly how I can fix it?

Frank G.

Answer (score 0):

The backup process in the admin is known to break, especially if any timeout sets are ignored, the process that is generating the db backup simply never finishes.  With you being on Windows 2008, there may be other possible issues.

You should be able to use `cmd.exe` to get to `mysqldump` from your MySQL bin installation.  This would be the ideal approach to ensure you've got a good db backup without the need of any timeout/broken files, etc.

- https://john-dugan.com/dump-and-restore-mysql-databases-in-windows/

Hope this helps!

---

For example, I'm not sure if [`Triggers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) have been supported in the DB Backup area of Magento, with MySQLDump you're almost always better off:

- https://github.com/molotovbliss/Envalo_Backup
- https://gist.github.com/molotovbliss/c176f2140232a0ba556f

Comment: mySQLDump Rules, Magento Backup Drools... The fantastically broken 1.6.2.0 backup put me off Magento's backup system for good. 2 hours and a 900MB file for 10x data expansion over actual content (dang, that was after compression 90MB from 1.5.1.0 vs 900MB from 1.6.2.0, hmm?) And totally corrupt content. The current one that does an atmosphereic strike on any suPHP site by permissions changes is kind of hilarious. Why bother when you can have 30-60 second full backups?